# Using groovy metaClass to mock out Shiro SecurityUtils in bootstrap

Tags: grails, groovy, metaprogramming, shiro, bootstrapping

For further background, see http://grails.markmail.org/message/62w2xpbgneapmhpd

I'm trying to mock out the Shiro SecurityUtils.getSubject() method in my BootStrap.groovy.  I decided on this approach because the Subject builder in the latest Shiro version isn't available in the current version of the Nimble plugin (which I'm using).  I decided to try playing with the SecurityUtils.metaClass but I have a feeling I'm missing something very fundamental about how metaClasses work.  For reference, here's my Trackable class:

```
    abstract class Trackable {
       User createdBy
       Date dateCreated
       User lastUpdatedBy
       Date lastUpdated

       static constraints = {
           lastUpdated(nullable:true)
           lastUpdatedBy(nullable:true)
           createdBy(nullable:true)
       }

       def beforeInsert = {
           def subject

           try {
               subject = SecurityUtils.subject
           } catch (Exception e) {
               log.error "Error obtaining the subject.  Message is [${e.message}]"
           }

           createdBy = (subject ? User.get( subject.principal ) :
User.findByUsername("admin"))
       }

       def beforeUpdate = {
           def subject

           try {
               subject = SecurityUtils.subject
           } catch (Exception e) {
               log.error "Error obtaining the subject.  Message is [${e.message}]"
           }

           lastUpdatedBy = (subject ? User.get( subject.principal ) :
User.findByUsername("admin"))
       }
   }
```

In my BootStrap.groovy, I have this:

```
   def suMetaClass = new ExpandoMetaClass(SecurityUtils)

   suMetaClass.'static'.getSubject = {[getPrincipal:{2}, toString:{"Canned Subject"}] as Subject}

   suMetaClass.initialize()

   SecurityUtils.metaClass = suMetaClass
```

And that works... sort of.  If I print out the subject from BootStrap.groovy I get "Canned Subject".  If I try to create and save instances of subclasses of Trackable, I get:

> ```
> No SecurityManager accessible to this method, either bound to
> the org.apache.shiro.util.ThreadContext or as a vm static
> singleton.  See the org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils.getSubject()
> method JavaDoc for an explanation of expected environment
> configuration.
> ```

Am I missing something integral about how metaClasses work?

Comment: I wonder if this might be related since Grails 1.1.1 is on Groovy 1.6.3?  http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-3873

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was happening.  In my BootStrap I was doing something like this:

```
def init = { servletContext->
  switch (Environment.current.name) {
    case "local":
      def suMetaClass = new ExpandoMetaClass(SecurityUtils)
      suMetaClass.'static'.getSubject = {[getPrincipal:{2}, toString:{"Canned Subject"}] as Subject}
      suMetaClass.initialize()
      SecurityUtils.metaClass = suMetaClass

      new TrackableSubClass().save()

      //Create some other domain instances

      SecurityUtils.metaClass = null
  }
  //Create a couple domain instances that aren't environment specific
}
```

I added some debug statements and saw that the errors I was seeing were happening at the end of the init closure.  I did some googling to double check how to flush my Hibernate session.  Then I made the following changes:

```
def sessionFactory

def init = { servletContext->
  switch (Environment.current.name) {
    case "local":
      def suMetaClass = new ExpandoMetaClass(SecurityUtils)
      suMetaClass.'static'.getSubject = {[getPrincipal:{2}, toString:{"Canned Subject"}] as Subject}
      suMetaClass.initialize()
      SecurityUtils.metaClass = suMetaClass

      new TrackableSubClass().save()

      //Create some other domain instances

      sessionFactory.currentSession.flush()

      SecurityUtils.metaClass = null
  }
  //Create a couple domain instances that aren't environment specific
}
```

That seems to have completely resolved the issue and now I should be able to remove the cumbersome try/catch blocks from Trackable.  :-)